# Use POSTMAN to authenticate to OPENID server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman, openid-connect, keycloak

I'm new to OpenID and OAuth 2.0.

I have an API of my own (it´s not in .net core but in .net 4.6) and I'm trying to use *Postman* by sending a request with an access token to access a **[Authorize]** resource in a API application of my own.

The api is configured to invoke the OpenID server in Implicit Mode, so I can get a **access_token** and use it from another client.

I don't have any problems when I debug my application; it authenticates against the OAUTH server and saves the state, but for some reason, when I try to send a request to the resource of my API, it still redirects me to the Authentication page of the OAUTH server as if I wasn't logged in.

This is the Startup in my API:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieName = "AuthCookieCoolApp",

        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = OidcAuthority,
            ClientId = OidcClientId,
            //ClientSecret = OidcClientSecret,
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
            RedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
            // ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdTokenToken,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                MessageReceived = notification =>
                {
                    var message = notification.ProtocolMessage;
                    var accesstoken = message.AccessToken;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Maybe it has something to do with the cookies, but I'm not sure.

Thing is, This works fine when I debug my asp.net app: the endpoints marked with the [Authorize] attribute are only allowed when authenticated in the OAuth Server. But for some reason, I cannot use this from Postman:

First, I send this request to get an access_token:

[image]

Then I try to use that same obtained Access Token in a different request invoking the [Autorize] method of my API, but it redirects me to the login page of the OAuth server:

[image]

I'm probably setting something wrong in the API, not sure what.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Header `authorize` looks suspicious. Usually `Authorization` header is used for authentication. But you may have custom implementation, where `authorize` header is valid.

Comment: Hi, I don't have custom implementation, plus Autorize header seems to work when I debug in browser.